# How to structure these SQL queries so they are perfect SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have to structure these queries so they are perfect SQL. The queries need to be for a SQL Server database, I have a database `StoresDB`, a table `items_table`.

I need to retrieve the

1. total number of items within this table
2. The number of item where the price is higher or equal than £10 - the column name is amount
3. The list of items in the computer category - column name ='comp_id' sorted by decreased amount.

For the above requests I have attempted the below:

1. `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM items_table`
2. `Select * from items_table where amount >= 10`
3. `Select * from items_table where comp_id = ’electronics’ desc`

I am very new to SQL and not sure if I have attempted this correctly.

Comment: What exactly the perfect SQL is? your three queries look ok. 1st query is correct. 2nd query: replace price with amount. 3rd query, make a join to comp table.

Comment: You can improve a) by using `SELECT COUNT (1) FROM items_table`. This way the Server does not need to look up all the data on the hard disk. If you don't want to go with 1 to be more clear in your code please just select the primary key column instead of *.

Comment: @RAS ok thanks, but question c doesn't state that there is a comp table it just states the list of items in the computer category and the column name is comp_id?

Comment: @MarkusDeibel, I think this is a generally false statement. Count(*) and count(1) should produce the same query plan in Sql-server-2008

Comment: @Rajin, unfortunately, your question doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @RAS, u'r right all servers should be implemented to catch it. Just making sure ;)

Comment: @MarkusDeibel: there is absolutely no difference whatsoever between `count(*)` and `count(1)` and there never was - not even 10 years ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a) Looks correct.

b) You are being asked for a count but are querying a list.

```
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM items_table WHERE price >= 10
```

c) This one looks good but you are missing an `ORDER BY` statement.

```
    SELECT * FROM items_table WHERE catID='electronics' ORDER BY price DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe is good to know few things when writing this sort of query:

a) `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM items_table`

This query is written correctly.

b) `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM items_table WHERE amount >= 10`

Query is OK, but choose to create indexes which cover WHERE clause, in this case, is good to have non-clustered index on `amount` column

c) `SELECT * FROM items_table WHERE comp_id = 'electronics' ORDER BY price DESC`

With this last query you have an issue that searching all columns in result, with `SELECT * ...` which is considered like bad practice in production, so you need to put in SELECT list only columns which are really needed, not all columns. Also you can create non-clustered index on comp_id column, with included columns from SELECT list.